# Merge multiple lists with variable length "popping" elements from each

Tags: c#, sorting, merge

I'd like to sort multiple lists (variable number of them) into single list, but keeping the specific order. For example:

```
List A: { 1,2,3,4,5 }
List B: { 6,7,8 }
List C: { 9,10,11,12 }

Result List: { 1,6,9,2,7,10,3,8,11,4,12,5 }
```

The only idea I got was to remove the first element from each list and put it into resulting set (and repeat until all lists are empty), but maybe there is a better way that doesn't require to create copy of each list and doesn't affect the original lists as well?

Comment: Loop through each list from 0 to length and put each corresponding element in the new list? By that I mean A[0], B[0], C[0], A[1], (...).

Comment: And how do I know when to stop looping? Some kind of flag "hasElements", set to false in the beginning of loop and modified to true if any list still has greater count?

Comment: There is [Enumerable.Zip<Tfirst, Tsecond>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I like the Zip idea! Will give it a try.

Comment: @Mark - Zip should do it, so use that instead of manually doing it like I mentioned (although it may be a fun "learning experience"). But to answer your question, you could do the following: determine which list is longest, loop from 0 to "longest", if this index is still within each list.Length (moving from A > B > C), add it to the result set. I can post an answer because I'm bored.

Comment: I'm afraid Zip only concats 2 lists, so it doesn't suit my needs. Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Mark - Can't you call Zip twice? I'm not too terribly familiar with how it works...

Comment: I don't know how many lists there would be, I get them dynamically (list of lists).

Comment: `Zip` wants all lists to have *equal* `Length`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more flexible use

```
 public static string MergeArrays(params IList<int>[] items)
    {

        var result = new List<int>();
        for (var i = 0; i < items.Max(x => x.Count); i++)
            result.AddRange(from rowList in items where rowList.Count > i select rowList[i]);

        return string.Join(",", result);
    }
```

.

```
        var a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        var b = new List<int>() { 6, 7, 8 };
        var c = new List<int>() { 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 2, 1 };

        var r = MergeArrays(a, b, c);
```

Comment: can you pls change name of your ```Foo2``` function to something meaningful?

Comment: Find you're looking for hairy:)

Comment: Yeach, ```MergeArray``` looks almost ideal. (but ```MergeArrays``` will be better :P)

Comment: Among others, this solution looks simple enough to be understandable for others, even if it isn't the fastest. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using `IEnumerator<T>` to enumerate lists while they have items:

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources) {
  List<IEnumerator<T>> enums = sources
    .Select(source => source.GetEnumerator())
    .ToList();

  try {
    while (enums.Any()) {
      for (int i = 0; i < enums.Count;)
        if (enums[i].MoveNext()) {
          yield return enums[i].Current;

          i += 1;
        }
        else {
          // exhausted, let's remove enumerator
          enums[i].Dispose();
          enums.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
  }
  finally {
    foreach (var en in enums)
      en.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Test

```
List<int> A = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> B = new List<int>() { 6, 7, 8 };
List<int> C = new List<int>() { 9, 10, 11, 12 };

var result = Merge(A, B, C)
  .ToList();

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

The outcome is

```
1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 10, 3, 8, 11, 4, 12, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no sense in over complicating this in my opinion, why not use a simple for loop to accomplish what you need?

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8 };
List<int> list3 = new List<int> { 9, 10, 11, 12 };
List<int> resultList = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count || i < list2.Count || i < list3.Count; i++)
{
    if (i < list1.Count) resultList.Add(list1[i]);
    if (i < list2.Count) resultList.Add(list2[i]);
    if (i < list3.Count) resultList.Add(list3[i]);
}
```

Result: 1,6,9,2,7,10,3,8,11,4,12,5

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple way. It was fun to write up anyway.
No, it isn't the best, but it works and you could expand it to suit your needs of using a `List<List<int>>` very easily.

```
//Using arrays for simplicity, you get the idea.
int[] A = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] B = { 6, 7, 8 };
int[] C = { 9, 10, 11, 12 };

List<int> ResultSet = new List<int>();

//Determine this somehow. I'm doing this for simplicity.
int longest = 5; 

for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++)
{
    if (i < A.Length)
        ResultSet.Add(A[i]);
    if (i < B.Length)
        ResultSet.Add(B[i]);
    if (i < C.Length)
        ResultSet.Add(C[i]);
}

//ResultSet contains: { 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 10, 3, 8, 11, 4, 12, 5 }
```

As you can see, just pop this out into a method and loop through your lists of lists, properly determining the max length of all lists.

Comment: ```int longest = Math.Max(A.Length, Math.Max(B.Length, C.Length));``` OR ```int longest = new[] {A.Length, B.Length, C.Length}.Max();```

Comment: You could certainly implement @tym32167's max length code! The second one would probably be easier since you mention a `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: Can you pls just update your answer with any of solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Shortest and probably slowest solution

```
int[] A = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] B = { 6, 7, 8 };
int[] C = { 9, 10, 11, 12 };


var arrs = new[] { A, B, C };
var merged = Enumerable.Range(0, arrs.Max(a => a.Length))
    .Select(x => arrs.Where(a=>a.Length>x).Select(a=>a[x]))
    .SelectMany(x=>x)
    .ToArray();
```

upd.

Another way to solve - I just refactored @Sinatr answer.

```
static IEnumerable<T> XYZ<T>(IEnumerable<IList<T>> lists)
{
    if (lists == null)  
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    var index = 0;

    while (lists.Any(l => l.Count > index))
    {
        foreach (var list in lists)     
            if (list.Count > index)         
                yield return list[index];       
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can be further shortened `for (int index = 0; lists.Any(l => l.Count > index); index++) {...}` instead of `var index = 0; while(...) {... index++}`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko aa, thats almost same, just 3 lines can be combined to one, not a big difference. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var b = new List<int>() { 6, 7, 8 };
    var c = new List<int>() { 9, 10, 11, 12 };

    var abc = XYZ<int>(new[] { a, b, c }).ToList();
}

static IEnumerable<T> XYZ<T>(IEnumerable<IList<T>> lists)
{
    if (lists == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    var finished = false;
    for (int index = 0; !finished; index++)
    {
        finished = true;
        foreach (var list in lists)
            if (list.Count > index) // list != null (prior checking for count)
            {
                finished = false;
                yield return list[index];
            }
    }
}
```

I had to use use `IList` to have indexer and `Count`. It doesn't creates anything (no enumerators, no lists, etc.), purely `yield return`.

Comment: Man, that's soo complicated. It hard to read this code at least for me.

Comment: @tym32167, the idea was to complement linq deferred execution. `XYZ<T>` doesn't produces anything until you actually start using results (e.g. call `ToList()`). It's bulletproof (note comment) and can be used with any type (aka generic). The logic, I agree, somewhat unclear, but pretty simple: outer `foreach` to enumerate all lists you passed and inner `for` to return all elements by current index; `finished` is used to determine when to .. finish.

Comment: Yep, I already understand the code, but I believe that you can make it more readable. That ```for``` cycle with flag ```finished ``` .. dont know, I just personally dont like it. But ofcource your solution should work great.

Comment: I updated my answer, where I refactored your code. Pls take a look, what do you think about refactored code? Its almost same, but from my point it looks better just because It easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I create static method, which can merge any collections as you want:

```
public static class CollectionsHandling
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Merge collections to one by index
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of collection elements</typeparam>
    /// <param name="collections">Merging Collections</param>
    /// <returns>New collection {firsts items, second items...}</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] collections)
    {
        // Max length of sent collections
        var maxLength = 0;

        // Enumerators of all collections
        var enumerators = new List<IEnumerator<T>>();

        foreach (var item in collections)
        {
            maxLength = Math.Max(item.Count(), maxLength);
            if(collections.Any())
                enumerators.Add(item.GetEnumerator());
        }
        // Set enumerators to first item
        enumerators.ForEach(e => e.MoveNext());

        var result = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            // Add elements to result collection
            enumerators.ForEach(e => result.Add(e.Current));

            // Remobve enumerators, in which no longer have elements
            enumerators = enumerators.Where(e => e.MoveNext()).ToList();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Example of using:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var b = new List<int> { 6, 7, 8 };
    var c = new List<int> { 9, 10, 11, 12 };

    var result= CollectionsHandling.Merge(a, b, c);
}
```

When you understand how it works, it will be possible to reduce the method of smaller.

Comment: Oh, my.. this solution even worse that mine. Enumerators, ```for``` cycles and Linq inside one method. Soo uneffective. Can you count how much collections you are creating during this method?

Comment: Firstly, this method is faster than you blink.

Comment: Secondly, read the last string "When you understand how it works, it will be possible to reduce the method of smaller.".

Comment: Why do you think that its faster? And yeach, I red last string.

Comment: Use stopwatch and note the time for work. And please, do not waste my time on silly questions...

Comment: Ok, no problem. I will not talk with you. So, for future readers of this: from my point this solution uses too much memory, its hard to understand that code mess and probably slowest comparing with others answers.