# How to print two Linked List program

Tags: c#, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Please help me, i trying to use two Linked list because i want the result is just like my 2 array element. Here is my code

```
 class Program
{
    int[] info = { 74, 90, 80, 63 };
    int[] link = { 2, 6, 0, 3 };


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program newProgram = new StrukturData.Program();

        newProgram.Node();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void Node()
    {
        LinkedList<int> infoList = new LinkedList<int>(info);
        LinkedList<int> linkList = new LinkedList<int>(link);

        foreach (var item in infoList)
        {
            Console.Write(item + "  ");

            foreach (var back in linkList)
            {
                Console.Write(back + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput

```
74  2  6  0  3  90  2  6  0  3  80  2  6  0  3  63  2  6  0  3
```

What i was expected

```
74  2  90  6  80  0  63  3
```

I think the problem is in my foreach statement. Im sorry my english is bad so i cann't talking to much:(,  but i hope you guys can help me to get the result what i was expected :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768322/merge-multiple-lists-with-variable-length-popping-elements-from-each/40768526#40768526 my answer there will do for any `IEnumerable<T>`: `foreach (var item in Merge(infoList, linkList)) {...}`

Comment: Think about what you're doing, for every item in `infoList` you print that item then all of the `linkList`

Comment: if `infoList` and `linkList` have the *same* number of items you can use `Zip`: `infoList.Zip(linkList, (a, b) => new int[] {a, b}).SelectMany(x => x);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i trying use IEnumerable<T>: foreach (var item in Merge(infoList, linkList)) {...} and it's work . Thank you ;D

Comment: @BagusArya you can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Slai done, thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for universal solution (which may be complex though), please, have a look at

[Merge multiple lists with variable length "popping" elements from each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40768322/merge-multiple-lists-with-variable-length-popping-elements-from-each/40768526#40768526)

where my answer will do for *any* `IEnumerable<T>` (`LinkedList<int>`, `int[]` included) input:

```
 public void Node() {
   Console.Write(string.Join(" ", Merge(info, link)));
 }
```

Or if you insist on `LinkedList<T>`:

```
 public void Node() {
   LinkedList<int> infoList = new LinkedList<int>(info);
   LinkedList<int> linkList = new LinkedList<int>(link);

   Console.Write(string.Join(" ", Merge(infoList, linkList)));
 }
```

In case of you want to solve just your exact `LinkedList<int>` case:

```
 LinkedList<int> infoList = new LinkedList<int>(info);
 LinkedList<int> linkList = new LinkedList<int>(link); 

 // Enumerate each collection 
 using (var enInfo = infoList.GetEnumerator()) {
   using (var enLink = linkList.GetEnumerator()) {
     bool proceed = true;

     // until both exausted
     while (proceed) {
       proceed = false; 

       if (enInfo.MoveNext()) {
         proceed = true;

         Console.Write(enInfo.Current + "  ");
       }

       if (enLink.MoveNext()) {
         proceed = true;

         Console.Write(enLink.Current + "  ");
       } 
     }  
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how your loop should look like

```
int[] info = { 74, 90, 80, 63 };
int[] link = { 2, 6, 0, 3 };

for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(info.Length, link.Length); i++)
{
    Console.Write(info[i] + " ");
    Console.Write(link[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution works if the size of 2 arrays is the same.

Here is the new loop:

```
int max = Math.Max(infoList.Count,linkList.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        if (i < infoList.Count)
            Console.Write(infoList.ElementAt(i) + "  ");
        if (i < linkList.Count)
            Console.Write(linkList.ElementAt(i) + "  ");
    }
```